# I got notification of positive change in reputation but not listed in achievements

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

Today on StackOverflow site I got notification about +3 change in reputation but when I clicked on it, I am not able to see for which question or answer or comment I got these 3 reputation. I have noticed that this change is applied on my reputation but I cannot see it's explanation. [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3445193/mohini-mhetre)

[image: my profile achievements snap]

Comment: Related: [Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882) and [Topbar tells me about a +1 recovered from a deleted downvoted post, but detail view doesn't show it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that an answer you downvoted has been deleted. The downvote cost you 1 rep point to cast, and that rep is refunded if the answer is deleted. It may have been deleted by itself (users often delete their downvoted answers), or as part of the deletion of the question to which it responded.

If you look at [the reputation tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3445193/mohini-mhetre?tab=reputation), you will see the deleted post listed,<sup><sub>*</sub></sup> although since you don't have 10k reputation you won't be able to look at the post itself.

---

<sup><sub>*</sub></sup>As long as you have the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom ticked.